# Como hacer para que un textbox se refresque en un bucle For en C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Quiero que el textbox muestre el valor de i en cada iteracción que pasara cada 500 milisegundos, lo que pasa es que el textbox se frisa hasta que pasan todas las iteracciones y solo me muestra el ultimo valor.

````
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                texto.Text +=i.ToString();
            }
            
        }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr el resultado que esperas, debes utilizar programación asíncrona y hasta ahora la forma más fácil de lograrlo es con [async y await](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). *(lectura muy recomendada, mejor dicho... obligatoria)*

Afortunadamente este caso se resuelve con una simple modificación a tu código:

```
    //       | Agrega aquí la palabra async
    //       V
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            //  |
            //  V Elimina esta instrucción porque no quieres bloquear el hilo
            //Thread.Sleep(500);

            texto.Text += i.ToString();

            //  |  Agrega esta instrucción para esperar los 500 ms
            //  V
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
```

#### Advertencia:

Es importante destacar que `async void` sólo debe utilizarse en los manejadores de eventos (como en este caso).
Cualquier otro uso debe devolver una tarea, por ejemplo: `async Task` o `async Task<TResult>` [Leer más](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) *(otra lectura obligatoria)*

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

.
Hola.

Podrías implementar un timer.

```
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                //Thread.Sleep(500);
                texto.Text +=i.ToString();
            }
         
        }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = (1000);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
            timer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: con eso solo me mostrara una cadena vacia.

Comment: Exacto, me corrijo. Tu suspendes el form con la línea  ``` Thread.Sleep(500); ```.

Comment: Ahora bien, ¿deseas mostrar cada valor en uno? Porque solo estás concatenando.

Comment: he realizado un sudoku solver grafico en wpf(usando backtraking), el programa va bien pero me gustaria que en la aplicacion me muestre cada vez que el valor se ponga y quite(para hacerlo ver mas dinamico) si encuentro una solucion para el problema que plantee arriba la encontrare para este.

Comment: pues bien me gustaria que cuando el bucle inicie se muestre en el textbox el primer valor de la iteraccion, luego de pasados 500 milisegundos se muestre el segundo y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Oh vale.  No resuelvo lo del bucle aun, pero podrías implementar un timer y cargarlo en el evento **Load** del form. Agregué unas líneas.